# Pi4/Kodi media player

Tags: kodi, raspberry-pi-desktop

I have installed **Kodi LibreELEC on a Pi4 however, I am finding it will not play .mkv or .avi only mp4
Are there any solutions out there? I don't want to convert all my movies to MP4. Thanks for any info :)

Comment: what codec is used in the mkv and avi containers? I've never had issues with mkv that uses AVC video and AC-3 or AAC LC audio